# System.identityHashCode inverse?

Tags: java

is there any inverse function of System.identityHashCode (object) which is able to provide the value of the object from the result of System.identityHashCode (object)?

Comment: @Tunaki It's a really interesting question though. I know that `System.identityHashCode` isn't guaranteed to produce different results for different objects, but there must be a way to write native code to get the `Set` of all objects with a given hash.

Comment: It is *perhaps* possible with some **highly unstable** code, depending on how `identityHashCode` is implemented. Nobody should do it. You shouldn't do it. If you are thinking about doing it in real code, it is an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.identityHashCode()` returns a hash value for an object.
It is possible to have equal hash values for more then one object.
So revers function is **impossible by design**.

Comment: thanks , so is there any **function** which gives **reference of object** and an other one which provides **the value of the object** from the **result of this function**?

Comment: If you want to have a reference to an object you have to keep that reference somewhere (eg. Collection or Map).
If there is no any references to the object it can be destroyed by Garbage Collector.

You can access forgotten Object (if it wasn't destroyed) using Unsafe class methods, but this is quite complicated and for sure not recommended. :)